# Fill textbox with preceding label in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Form Filler with JavaScript that will take the value from the InputLabel field from the code below and put that value into the InputAnswer field.

```
<div id="pi58741row2" class="regComponentRow">
    <div id="piInputOption221812" class="regInputItem">
        <div id="piInputLabel221812" class="inputLabel">
            <font color="#C65E09">*</font>First Name
        </div><div id="piInputAnswer221812" class="inputAnswer">
            <input name="firstName" type="text" value="This is a test" maxlength="80" id="firstName" style="width:150px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been able to fill the field with my own text with the code below but the field might be used for something other than a First Name on occasion, so I want whatever the label is to be put into the field instead of the input name.

```
if (type == 'text') {
    if (!inp.value) {
        if (inp.name.indexOf('ame') != -1) {
            inp.value = 'First Name';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a hint if you want to associate text with an `<input>` use a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element; and the [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) element has been deprecated for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit easier to see how to do this if you format your HTML a bit:

```
<div id="pi58741row2" class="regComponentRow">
    <div id="piInputOption221812" class="regInputItem">
        <div id="piInputLabel221812" class="inputLabel">
            <font color="#C65E09">*</font>First Name
        </div>
        <div id="piInputAnswer221812" class="inputAnswer">
            <input name="firstName" type="text" value="This is a test" maxlength="80" id="firstName" style="width:150px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now we can readily see that the divs around the label and field are siblings, and that the `input` is inside the `inputAnswer` div. So if we select all the `inputAnswer` elements, we can get the text from the `inputLabel` in front of them and apply it to the `input` *inside* them.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inputAnswer"), function(answer) {
    var label = answer.previousElementSibling;
    var input = answer.querySelector("input");
    input.value = (label.innerText || label.textContent).trim();
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inputAnswer"), function(answer) {
  var label = answer.previousElementSibling;
  var input = answer.querySelector("input");
  input.value = (label.innerText || label.textContent).trim();
});
```

```html
<div id="pi58741row2" class="regComponentRow">
  <div id="piInputOption221812" class="regInputItem">
    <div id="piInputLabel221812" class="inputLabel">
      <font color="#C65E09">*</font>First Name
    </div>
    <div id="piInputAnswer221812" class="inputAnswer">
      <input name="firstName" type="text" value="This is a test" maxlength="80" id="firstName" style="width:150px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pi58741row3" class="regComponentRow">
  <div id="piInputOption221813" class="regInputItem">
    <div id="piInputLabel221813" class="inputLabel">
      <font color="#C65E09">*</font>Last Name
    </div>
    <div id="piInputAnswer221813" class="inputAnswer">
      <input name="firstName" type="text" value="This is a test" maxlength="80" id="lastName" style="width:150px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A few notes on that:

- As you can see, we're using `forEach` from arrays even though the return value of `document.querySelectorAll` isn't an array. It's array-like, which is sufficient. Older browsers like IE8 may need a shim/polyfill for `forEach`.
- `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` are supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.
- We're allowing for the possibility that the browser uses `innerText` or `textContent`. They're similar, but slightly different, properties and some browsers support one, others support the other, and some may even support both. For what we're doing, it doesn't matter, so we just try both via the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).
- Some browsers may not have `String#trim` (which I used at the end). It can easily be shimmed/polyfilled, though.

---

Or if you're using jQuery and just didn't remember to tag it:

```
$(".inputAnswer").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $label = $this.prev(".inputLabel"); // Only if adjacent
    var $input = $this.find("input");
    $input.val($.trim($label.text()));
});
```

With the modern features of browsers (`querySelectorAll`, `forEach`, `String#trim`), it doesn't really buy us much in this case.

---

Side note: The `font` tag has been deprecated for years, and you weren't using it for what it was originally meant for anyone. Suggest a `span` element:

```
<span style="color: #C65E09">*</span>
```

or better yet:

```
<span class="flag">*</span>
```

...and do the coloring in CSS.

---

Side note 2: The correct way to label inputs is to use a `label` element, relating them either with containment (putting the `input` *inside* the `label`) or with the `for` attribute on the `label` referring to the `id` on the `input`. (If you want your `label` to be a block, like `div`, you can do that with CSS.) You might consider something along these lines:

```
<div id="pi58741row2" class="regComponentRow">
    <div id="piInputOption221812" class="regInputItem">
        <label for="firstName">
            <span class="flag">*</span>First Name
        </label>
        <div id="piInputAnswer221812" class="inputAnswer">
            <input name="firstName" type="text" value="This is a test" maxlength="80" id="firstName" style="width:150px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```